# Unable to center the content within a Material UI TableCell

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have `TableCell` which shows a `status` and a `Button`. I want them to be vertically stacked and centered in the cell. I am able to get either working separately but not together. I am using `FlexBox` to vertically stack the elements. Relevant code show below.

```
<TableCell align="center" sx={{color:'warning.main', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center', maxWidth: 200}}>
   {status}
  <Button variant='contained'
    onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
    sx={{ m: 1 }}>
       Add manual payment
   </Button>
 </TableCell>
```

The output is like so:
[image]
Not sure what is missing here. It works fine if I don't use FlexBox but then the `status` and `Button` stack horizontally. I have tried `alignItems`, `textAlign` and all similar properties I could think of. Using MUI version 5.1.1,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `textAlign: 'center'` and `margin: 'auto'` to `TableCell`

- `textAlign: 'center'` is for status text center
- `margin: 'auto'` is to center status and button when they have spare space from both sides (left and right)

```
<TableCell align="center" sx={{color:'warning.main', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center', maxWidth: 200, margin: 'auto', textAlign: 'center'}}>
   {status}
  <Button variant='contained'
    onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
    sx={{ m: 1 }}>
       Add manual payment
   </Button>
 </TableCell>
```

Comment: That worked thanks! Any idea why there is a gap in the separator lines? Since it is centered now, the gap is visible on both sides.

Comment: Hmm it's hard to guess. Possibly, it's from margin or fixed size @avocado